# A book that introduces Philosophy

Tags: reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get started with philosophy without getting overwhelmed quickly?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/how-to-get-started-with-philosophy-without-getting-overwhelmed-quickly)

What is a good book (Or online resource) that introduces Philosophy and the methods of Philosophers, not by example only, but also with clear statements of what is being done?

I am reading a book on Philosophy of Science, and I understood the idea of Inductivism, and how Hume disregarded it as a real (actual) justification for science; but then, I was (briefly?) introduced to 10 arguments of why we should consider it as "working" (i.e. providing a justification). When that happened, I found myself bombarded with arguments that I mostly couldn't comprehend (either did not understand or they seemed unconvincing).

I'm not interested in a book that tells me to argue, and shows me some arguments. I'm interested in a book that clearly illustrates how a philosopher does Philosophy. That would be more convenient and more helpful. In my case, I have short time to finish the book on Philosophy of Science, and so I want to be able to do it with some clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You're laboring under a false presumption if you think there's such a thing as a book which will tell you what it is philosopher's do that doesn't include a description of how basic formal arguments work. In a sense, that *is* how philosophers "do philosophy".

To that end, though, I've been greatly enjoying the book [The Philosopher's Toolkit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0631228748). You won't be able to avoid reading about some basics of formal argumentation, but it's proven to be quite good at summarizing the methods.